# Diference between dual spaces

Tags: vector-spaces, duality-theorems

What is the diference between Algebraic Dual Space and Topologic Dual Space in Normed Vector spaces  with $dim=\infty$

Comment: If the question is regarding the definitions: The algebraic dual is the space of all linear functionals, while the topological dual is the space of all _bounded_ linear functionals. (If that doesn't answer the question  you need to clarify what you're asking...)

Comment: Algebraic dual space is much larger because in infinite dimension not all the linear forms are continuous

Comment: But of course showing that there is a discontinuous linear functional on a Banach space requires the Axiom of Choice (or its consequence, the Hahn-Banach theorem).  For some incomplete normed vector spaces, however, it is easy without choice.

Answer (score 0):

By definition the difference is clear:

The algebraic dual space of a vector space $V$ is the space of all linear functionals on $V$.

The topological dual space is the space of continuous linear functionals on $V$.

The problem is to show that there exists non continuous linear functional so that the  topological dual space is a proper subspace of the algebraic dual space.

For finite dimensional vector spaces we can prove that [any linear functional is bounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discontinuous_linear_map#A_linear_map_from_a_finite-dimensional_space_is_always_continuous) (so it's continuous), but for infinite dimensional vector spaces we can prove, using the axiom of choice, that there exist unbounded linear functionals, so the two dual spaces do not coincide. 
But the proof is not constructive, in the sense that we cannot exibit explicitly a not continuous linear functional for a complete space.

Comment: Hm, so all i have is to give a counter example of a continuous function in the algebraic space and i could prove they are indeeed diferent?

Comment: The situation is a bit more complex because , in general, we can only prove that a non continuous functional exists but we cannot find it constructively, so we cannot give an explicit counterexample.